# Using case when clause in insert values

Tags: sql, db2

So I have this insert statement, and I need to check another table before setting the number1 & number2 columns. I've used the case when statement in the values part of the insert statement. Is there a better way of doing this without duplicating code when setting both of these columns.

```
INSERT INTO history (
    user_id
    ,number1
    ,number2
    )
VALUES (
    'user1'
    ,CASE 
        WHEN (
                SELECT user_id
                FROM old_history
                WHERE user_id = 'user1'
                ) IS NOT NULL
            THEN 12.3
        ELSE NULL
        END
    ,CASE 
        WHEN (
                SELECT user_id
                FROM old_history
                WHERE user_id = 'user1'
                ) IS NOT NULL
            THEN 15
        ELSE NULL
        END
    );
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Aggregation functions conveniently return `NULL` when there is no match.  So, I think this is the simplest method:

```
INSERT INTO history (user_id, number1, number2)
    SELECT 'user1', MAX(12.3), MAX(15)
    FROM old_history
    WHERE user_id = 'user1';
```

The use of aggregation functions `MAX()` makes this an aggregation query, which is guaranteed to return 1 row.  The second and third columns are `NULL` when there are no matching rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO history (user_id, number1, number2)
SELECT 
 'user1'
, case when count(1)=1 then 12.3 end
, case when count(1)=1 then 15   end
FROM old_history
WHERE user_id = 'user1';
```